# Rails application.js error on Production: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

I am getting this error from my line 1 of my application.js file:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number   application-b975feabda9124d54cd2e23989649e07.js:1
```

The error is coming from a "2" in the comment section of jquery:

```
2
 * http://jquery.com/
 *
 * Copyright 2011, John Resig
```

When working it looks like this:

```
/*!
 * jQuery JavaScript Library v1.7.2
 * http://jquery.com/
 *
 * Copyright 2011, John Resig
```

I get no errors in my Dev environment. Only after pushing to Heroku and application.js is compiled.

**UPDATE**

I've searched all js files in assets/javascripts and couldn't find a 2 relating to the problem. I suspect it is related to the jquery-rails gem because when I downgraded (as a test) the gem to 2.0.1 the 2 became a 1.

Any and all ideas are appreciated!

Comment: Did you try to remove 2?

Comment: It looks to me like you have a file in your development js folder with a "2" in it, which is being concatenated into your production javascript file.  Your production and development javascript files are clearly different anyway. Try re-compiling the production file.

Comment: I've searched all js files and couldn't find a 2 relating to the problem. I suspect it is related to the jquery-rails gem because when i downgraded the gem to 2.0.1 the 2 became a 1. any ideas there?

Comment: I can confirm that this is happening to me too. Some asset files will get "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error" inserted at the top of the file: https://d2dnzw0oqnl06s.cloudfront.net/assets/editors-a1b87683431df94da1eb0608e20444ef.js. This is nowhere in my code, and seems to be inserted at asset compilation on Heroku. I have no idea what's going on. Any help?

Comment: My problem was caused by Rails caching static assets, and cloudfront caching the error with the partial asset code. http://jackchu.com/2011/09/20/rails-asset-pipeline-content-delivery-networks-and-rack-cache/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused by Rails caching static assets. I was able to fix this issue by preventing the static assets from being cached as described in [this article](http://jackchu.com/2011/09/20/rails-asset-pipeline-content-delivery-networks-and-rack-cache/) (thanks [Ronze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/600540/ronze))

I added this to my application.rb file:

```
# config/application.rb
require 'rack/cache'

if !Rails.env.development? && !Rails.env.test?
  config.middleware.insert_before Rack::Cache, Rack::Static, urls: [config.assets.prefix],     root: 'public'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please do the below steps

a) Check all Java Script files included,

- you might have added 2 by mistake in any of the JS files, check and remove it if its the case.
- check comment opening and closing tags, correct it if its the case.

b) if any of the above cases were applicable then commit and push updates to heroku and check.

c) if its not the case, try running the application in production environment locally by compiling the assets and see whether it still exists. Also please share the JS files so that we can check it for you.